# Combined array is not working in php

Tags: php, html, arrays

My Array:

Array Set One:

> ```
> $values = array( "Paid Search Ads" => "$avg_2_1",
>                "TV" => "$avg_2_2" , 
>                "Radio" => "$avg_2_3",
>                "Print Ads" => "$avg_2_4",
>                "Social Media Posts" => "$avg_2_5",
>                "Facebook Ads" => "$avg_2_6",               
>                "LinkedIn Ads" => "$avg_2_7",
>                "Twitter Ads" => "$avg_2_8",
>                "YouTube" => "$avg_2_9",
>                "Vimeo" => "$avg_2_10",
>                "Email Marketing" => "$avg_2_11",
>                "Email Newsletter" => "$avg_2_12",
>                "Pay-per-click Ads" => "$avg_2_13",
>                "Blogs" => "$avg_2_14",
>                "eBooks" => "$avg_2_15",
>                "Online Videos" => "$avg_2_16",
>                "Video Ads" => "$avg_2_17",
>                "Other" => "$avg_2_18",
>                "None of these" => "$avg_2_19"
>               );
>
> $values = array_unique($values);  
> arsort($values);  
> $values = array_slice($values, 0, 5);
> ```

Array Set 2:

> ```
> $color_array = array(             "color1" => "#f0f0f0",
>        "color2" => "#c5c5c5", 
>        "color3" => "#000000",
>        "color4" => "#565656",
>        "color5" => "#242423"          );
> ```

Out Put Section:

```
<?php 
      foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
           //echo "$key = $val\n";
           foreach($color_array as $col => $colcode){
                echo'<tr><td>'.$val.'%</td>
                <td class="barWidth vMiddle">
                <div class="Hzbar" style="width:'.$val.'% !important; background:'.$colcode.'"></div>
                </td>
                <td>'.$key.'Paid Search Ads</td>
                </tr>';
           }
      }
      ?>
```

Current Output:

![enter image description here][1]

But Expected output is ONLY 5 RESULT with 5 different colors :(

EXPECTED OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: can you paste the whole code? it's hard to tell from what you pasted, but it might be a loop inside a loop

Comment: Its because you have 2 loops where in the first loop there are 5 records and in the second array there are also 5 records. So, when loop continues, it goes upto 5x5 i.e. 25 times and that's why you got 25 record output.

Comment: @UziKilon: yes, but the code i pasted is responsible for all the output. Yes you are right, there is a loop inside another loop. I just can figure how to make 5 iteration for both loop at a time. right now it is rotating 5x5 = 25 times :(

Comment: @prava: yes I know that. Just trying to find the solution..

Comment: you have 5 colors **for each** item in the first array. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? seems like the code is doing the right thing.

Comment: I want to call 3 variables in one single loop. dont know how :(

Comment: @UziKilon: Yes, the code is right. I need to combine the 2 array in such way so that the i can call the 3 variables in single loop

Comment: How is it supposed to work? Which color goes with which output?

Comment: I have all working.. I am just stuck with the random color setting. Sorry about my English

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

```
<?php
foreach ($values as $key => $val) {
    foreach($color_array as $col => $colcode){
        echo'                                
            <tr>
                <td>'.$val.'%</td>
                <td class="barWidth vMiddle">
                    <div class="Hzbar" style="width:'.$val.'% !important; background:'.$colcode.'"></div>
                </td>
                <td>'.$key.'Paid Search Ads</td>
            </tr>
        ' ;

        unset($color_array[$col]);
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Note: This is the solution if we assign the first 5 records of the first array with each of the equal order of the second array.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
$vk=0;
    foreach($values  as $val) { //echo "$key = $val\n";
        $vk++;

        $ck=0;
        foreach($color_array as $col => $colcode){
            $ck++;
            if( $vk==$ck){
                echo'                                
                <tr>
                <td>'.$val.'%</td>
                <td class="barWidth vMiddle">
                <div class="Hzbar" style="width:'.$val.'% !important; background:'.$colcode.'"></div>
                </td>
                <td>'.$key.'Paid Search Ads</td>
                </tr>
                ' ;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you check the the array $values output

for example,

```
$values = array(
"Paid Search Ads" => "sample",
   "TV" => "sample" , 
   "Radio" => "sample",
   "Print Ads" => "colin",
   "Social Media Posts" => "colin",
   "Facebook Ads" => "colin",               
   "LinkedIn Ads" => "colin",
   "Twitter Ads" => "sample",
   "YouTube" => "sample2",
   "Vimeo" => "sample2",
   "Email Marketing" => "sample2",
   "Email Newsletter" => "sample2",
   "Pay-per-click Ads" => "sample",
   "Blogs" => "sample3",
   "eBooks" => "sample",
   "Online Videos" => "sample3",
   "Video Ads" => "sample3",
   "Other" => "sample",
   "None of these" => "sample"
);

print_r($values);

$values = array_unique($values);

print_r($values);
```

the first output print

will print the entire array

the second output print

will print the unique filtered array

check php documentation

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

hope it would hope you..

Answer (score 1):

Can you change your array format to contain all the data you want? ie:

```
$values = array(
    "Paid Search Ads" => array(
       'width' => "$avg_2_1", 
       'color' => 'color1'
    ),
    "TV" => array(
        'width' => "$avg_2_2", 
        'color' => 'color2'
   ), 
    etc..
);
```

Then in your foreach:

```
foreach ($values as $key => $val) {                           

    echo'<tr>
            <td>'.$val['width'].'%</td>
            <td class="barWidth vMiddle">
                <div class="Hzbar" style="width:'.$val['width'].'% !important; background:'.$color_array[$val['color'].'"></div>
            </td>
            <td>'.$key.'Paid Search Ads</td>
         </tr>';
 }
```